# Regex too complicated when splitting a string

Tags: apex, reporting, string, csv

I am trying to get the Standard Report As a csv file and try to split the file and need to do some conditions.

But for the large amount of records am getting error as:

> Regex too complicated

Please help me out

**Apex**:

```
public List<String> convertToExcel(Id LiseReportId) {

    //LiseReportId is the standard report ID    
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/' + LiseReportId + '?csv=1');
        blobcontent = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : report.getContent();

        System.debug('blobcontent &&report: ' + report+':::'+blobcontent);
        String strfile =blobToString(blobcontent ,'ISO-8859-1');
        String[] strlineByCsvBody = new String[]{};
        strlineByCsvBody = strfile .split('\n');

        return strlineByCsvBody;

    }



    public String blobToString(Blob input, String inCharset){
            String strhex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(input);
            System.assertEquals(0, strhex.length() & 1);
            final Integer bytesCount = strhex.length() >> 1;
            String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
            for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
                bytes[i] =  strhex.mid(i << 1, 2);
            return EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), inCharset);
        }
```

Getting error at below line:

> strlineByCsvBody = strfile .split('\n')

Comment: @Eric..I Have seen your answer..For my case how can i do that ? I want the content as "ISO-8859-1" format.from report am directly converting it into csv.Please guide me

Comment: If you are converting it to a string why are you converting it to ISO-8859-1? If you must though, convert the body to a string and use the correct deliminator. The iterator works on a string so....you use it at the same spot you would do the split

Comment: I have not tried it but I believe that the string will parse fine using the method in the linked answer. Just ensure you are using the correct deliminator. All it does is split it by line. worth a shot, all you need is there. You could even run it via anon if needed with a test string

Comment: @Eric..It's worked fine..But the thing is it only retriving the first row ..I have tested with the sample code..       Id LiseReportId ='00O4E000000OsJq';
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/' + LiseReportId + '?csv=1'); Blob blobcontent = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : report.getContent();   String strfile =reportscheduler.blobToString(blobcontent ,'ISO-8859-1');                                        Utility_RowIterator r = New Utility_RowIterator(strfile ,'\n'); 
     String firstRow;    if(r.hasNext()) firstRow = r.next();